# How to get the background from multiple images by removing moving objects?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have taken multiple images of the same scene with a fixed camera which has moving objects in it. I don't understand how can I use these images in Python to  retrieve the background image by removing all the moving objects.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Images have been attached below:

In this case, I would expect the final image to be without any hands in it.

image1:[image]

image2:[image]

image3:[image]

Answer (score 7):

**Updated Answer**

I worked out how to do what I suggested below in Python - but there may be better ways - I am still a Python beginner!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Load images
im0 = np.array(Image.open('1.jpg'))
im1 = np.array(Image.open('2.jpg'))
im2 = np.array(Image.open('3.jpg'))

# Stack the 3 images into a 4d sequence
sequence = np.stack((im0, im1, im2), axis=3)

# Repace each pixel by mean of the sequence
result = np.median(sequence, axis=3).astype(np.uint8)

# Save to disk
Image.fromarray(result).save('result.png')
```

[image]

**Original Answer**

The easiest way is to take the median of each pixel across the 3 images because the 2 images without the hand will have values near each other and the one with the hand will be the outlier and the median filter removes outliers.

So, I don't mean you look at a 3x3 or 5x5 area of each image and calculate the median. Rather, I mean look at `pixel[0,0]` in image 1, 2 and 3 and take the median of those three values - you do that by sorting the 3 values into order and picking the middle value of the three sorted pixels as your output value. Then look at `pixel[0,1]` in all 3 images and repeat the process.

This is the result:

[image]

I didn't write the Python, I just did exactly the same thing with **ImageMagick** in Terminal like this:

```
convert 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg -evaluate-sequence median result.jpg
```

---

Just so you can see what I am doing, if I calculate the mean/average of the 3 pixels at each location, rather than the median, the hands will show up at just 1/3 of their original density:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Mark. This makes it work but if the object hasn't really moved much in the images then it makes the result very different. For instance, if the hand stayed in the same position and I moved it (vertically or horizontally) by only a few centimetres in the three pictures, the result would not remove the hand.

Comment: Agreed - my solution is only as good as the sample images supplied ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To answer partially your question check out Background substraction methods in OpenCV's tutorial:

https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html

What this does is identifying the changing pixels based on a series of pictures (or video) so you can process them later on.

Comment: I’ve tried this but it only returns the object in grayscale. I don’t really understand what to do after. One approach was to output the background image using the getBackground method but it doesn’t really seem to work either. Any further insight into this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at dense optical flow to segment the moving objects.

Here's the OpenCV's tutorial on it:

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_lucas_kanade.html